# changing connection strings at runtime

Tags: service, polling

I have a config file and a pollingservice with different methods in the polling service. What i want to happen is that when it hits a certain method in the polling service i want to change the connection string in the config file from:

```
<add name="Entity" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=dev;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=a;Password=asdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

to this:

```
 <add name="Entity" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=dev_Test;Initial Catalog=DB_Test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=a;Password=asdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Please assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to change the app.config file, you can do this :

```
  var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

  config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["Entity"].ConnectionString = YourNewConnectionString;
  config.Save();
```

If you only need to change the datasource is the inner connection string and you don't want to parse the entity connection string, you can use the connection string builders as so :

```
var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entity"].ConnectionString);
var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString);

sqlBuilder.DataSource = "dev_Test";

entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

var connectionString = entityBuilder.ToString();
```